# For test suite, replacing MYSQL by in memory HSQLDB is not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2, testng, hsqldb

We have an application where we use Struts, Spring, and hibernate.
Previously, we were using mysql databse for running test suites using testng framework.
Now we want to use “in memory” database of HSQLDB. 
We have made all the required code changes to use HSQLDB in “in memory” mode.

For ex.

Datasource url = jdbc:hsql:mem:TEST_DB

Username = sa

Password =

Driver = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

Hibernate dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect

Hibernate.hbm2ddl.aoto = create

```
   @Autowired
private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;
private static Connection dbConnection;
private static IDatabaseConnection dbUnitConnection;
private static IDataSet dataSet;
private MockeryHelper mockeryHelper;

    public void startUp() throws Exception {
mockeryHelper = new MockeryHelper();
        if (dbConnection == null) {
            dbConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
            dbUnitConnection = new DatabaseConnection(dbConnection);
            dbUnitConnection.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY, new HsqldbDataTypeFactory());
            dataSet = new XmlDataSet(new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/test-data.xml"));
        }
        DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT.execute(dbUnitConnection, dataSet);
}
```

We have done required code changes to our base class where we do startup and teardown of database before and after each test.
We use test-data.xml file from where we insert test data to created database using testng framework.  Now my questions  are

1.when I run  test case, database gets created and data is also inserted correctly. However, my respective daos return empty object list when I try to retrieve them from interceptors of struts.

2.We use HSQLDB version 1.8.0.10. Same configurations are made for other project. In that project, most of the test cases are running with success, however for some of them sorting order of data is incorrect.
We discovered that HSQLDB is case sensitive for sorting. And there is one property sql.ignore_case, when set to true, sorting becomes case insensitive. But this is not working for us.
Can someone please help in this?
 Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid `sql.ignore_case` is not available in your HSQLDB version, as it's not even in the last stable (2.2.9), contrary to what the docs say. However latest snapshots, as stated in [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/forums/forum/73674/topic/5574824), do include it. I'm not using 1.8 my self, but executing `SET IGNORECASE TRUE` before any table creation may work for you, it does in 2.2.9. If you really need 1.8, a third option may be to pick the relevant code from latest source, add it to 1.8 source and recompile, no idea how hard/easy this could be.